# Fetch array has invalid type <class 'numpy.ndarray'>, must be a string or Tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

There is one similar post but my error is from another different variable.

I have `object detection using tensorflow` as follows.

```
import numpy as np
import os
import tensorflow as tf
import cv2
from object_detection.utils import ops as utils_ops
from utils import label_map_util
from utils import visualization_utils as vis_util

PATH_TO_LABELS = os.path.join('NumberPlateDetection/Numplate_ssdmobilenetv1_fpn/', 'numberplate_label_map.pbtxt')
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('/media/nyan/697eb924-2fe2-4054-b4a7-1b7d9578ab8f/nyan/Documents/data/NumberPlate_old/videos/IMG_5716.MOV')
category_index = label_map_util.create_category_index_from_labelmap(PATH_TO_LABELS, use_display_name=True)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('NumberPlateDetection/Numplate_ssdmobilenetv1_fpn/inference_graph/model.ckpt.meta')
    saver.restore(sess, 'NumberPlateDetection/Numplate_ssdmobilenetv1_fpn/inference_graph/model.ckpt')


    image_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')
    boxes = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_boxes:0')
    scores = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_scores:0')
    cls = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_classes:0')
    num_detections = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('num_detections:0')

    while True:
        ret, image_np = cap.read()
        # Expand dimensions since the model expects images to have shape: [1, None, None, 3]
        image_np_expanded = np.expand_dims(image_np, axis=0)

        (box, score, clses, num_detection) = sess.run([boxes, scores, cls, num_detections], {image_tensor:image_np_expanded})
        boxes = box[0]
        scores = score[0]
        classes = clses[0]
        classes = classes.astype(np.uint8)
        num_detections = int(num_detection[0])
        vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
          image_np,
          boxes,
          classes,
          scores,
          category_index,
          instance_masks=None,
          use_normalized_coordinates=True,
          line_thickness=8)
        cv2.imshow("result", image_np)
        cv2.waitKey(1)
```

When I run I have error as

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nyan/venvpy3_cpu/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 300, in __init__
    fetch, allow_tensor=True, allow_operation=True))
  File "/home/nyan/venvpy3_cpu/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3490, in as_graph_element
    return self._as_graph_element_locked(obj, allow_tensor, allow_operation)
  File "/home/nyan/venvpy3_cpu/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3579, in _as_graph_element_locked
    types_str))
TypeError: Can not convert a ndarray into a Tensor or Operation.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/pdb.py", line 1661, in main
    pdb._runscript(mainpyfile)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/pdb.py", line 1542, in _runscript
    self.run(statement)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/bdb.py", line 431, in run
    exec(cmd, globals, locals)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/nyan/venvpy3_cpu/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/models/research/object_detection/platedetection_ckpt.py", line 28, in <module>
    (box, score, clses, num_detection) = sess.run([boxes, scores, cls, num_detections], {image_tensor:image_np_expanded})
  File "/home/nyan/venvpy3_cpu/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 929, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/home/nyan/venvpy3_cpu/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1137, in _run
    self._graph, fetches, feed_dict_tensor, feed_handles=feed_handles)
  File "/home/nyan/venvpy3_cpu/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 471, in __init__
    self._fetch_mapper = _FetchMapper.for_fetch(fetches)
  File "/home/nyan/venvpy3_cpu/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 261, in for_fetch
    return _ListFetchMapper(fetch)
  File "/home/nyan/venvpy3_cpu/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 370, in __init__
    self._mappers = [_FetchMapper.for_fetch(fetch) for fetch in fetches]
  File "/home/nyan/venvpy3_cpu/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 370, in <listcomp>
    self._mappers = [_FetchMapper.for_fetch(fetch) for fetch in fetches]
  File "/home/nyan/venvpy3_cpu/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 271, in for_fetch
    return _ElementFetchMapper(fetches, contraction_fn)
  File "/home/nyan/venvpy3_cpu/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 304, in __init__
    (fetch, type(fetch), str(e)))
TypeError: Fetch argument array([[5.77544332e-01, 8.45235586e-01, 6.43900394e-01, 9.07178044e-01],
       [5.33677042e-01, 4.86815065e-01, 5.80641329e-01, 5.77449381e-01],
       [4.74086463e-01, 8.70195180e-02, 5.24333954e-01, 1.79605111e-01],
       [5.19357920e-01, 4.99080241e-01, 5.94354272e-01, 5.73785603e-01],
       [5.82983911e-01, 8.45164299e-01, 6.39722884e-01, 9.40664649e-01],
       [4.97819275e-01, 4.99108940e-01, 5.69518626e-01, 5.63991427e-01],
       [4.78881955e-01, 1.06984094e-01, 5.30262947e-01, 1.93123356e-01],
       [4.74147946e-01, 7.63106495e-02, 5.15930593e-01, 1.53555691e-01],
       [5.25953293e-01, 4.86130446e-01, 5.71939588e-01, 5.59750021e-01],
       [4.64354783e-01, 8.78702700e-02, 5.15185475e-01, 1.42144859e-01],
       [5.40731013e-01, 4.96525466e-01, 5.90277135e-01, 5.89240730e-01],
       [6.48492575e-01, 1.36446729e-01, 7.56026268e-01, 2.32635275e-01],
       [4.54677820e-01, 9.66271162e-02, 5.39422929e-01, 2.08910465e-01],
       [4.61367697e-01, 9.85105634e-02, 5.36004603e-01, 1.70391887e-01],
       [4.63144124e-01, 0.00000000e+00, 5.07749021e-01, 3.52073647e-03],
       [5.63846111e-01, 8.45380187e-01, 6.23896122e-01, 9.11140084e-01],
       [4.69701201e-01, 6.63738027e-02, 5.41866899e-01, 1.83118671e-01],
       [4.77697611e-01, 5.06144345e-01, 5.42844176e-01, 5.60523808e-01],
       [4.72879499e-01, 6.01597130e-05, 5.19583941e-01, 2.92058010e-03],
       [5.12202442e-01, 4.92434919e-01, 6.10050261e-01, 5.93318999e-01],
       [4.63009596e-01, 6.20467886e-02, 5.24990618e-01, 1.64958715e-01],
       [6.13893151e-01, 9.94723976e-01, 6.61991119e-01, 9.98004138e-01],
       [4.53765631e-01, 0.00000000e+00, 4.97960925e-01, 3.26656410e-03],
       [6.27439976e-01, 9.93734777e-01, 6.73767447e-01, 9.97623742e-01],
       [5.66576362e-01, 8.47537696e-01, 6.28735662e-01, 9.50264513e-01],
       [6.90762818e-01, 3.60847414e-01, 7.64203012e-01, 4.26695585e-01],
       [4.83208567e-01, 1.36616826e-01, 5.39002538e-01, 1.87182754e-01],
       [4.69947368e-01, 1.26561165e-01, 5.23706973e-01, 1.83843672e-01],
       [5.13909400e-01, 0.00000000e+00, 5.66110313e-01, 2.27159658e-03],
       [4.83525634e-01, 0.00000000e+00, 5.33509970e-01, 8.35428480e-04],
       [5.99805713e-01, 9.96134222e-01, 6.48686290e-01, 9.99062121e-01],
       [5.64034224e-01, 8.48343968e-01, 6.62548661e-01, 9.65659022e-01],
       [5.38653016e-01, 5.33363700e-01, 5.93894958e-01, 5.86480379e-01],
       [5.25070310e-01, 4.74877059e-01, 5.88969350e-01, 5.65924466e-01],
       [6.08664870e-01, 9.81623173e-01, 6.55121446e-01, 9.92417455e-01],
       [6.22447193e-01, 9.83231008e-01, 6.65400684e-01, 9.93343532e-01],
       [4.47022170e-01, 8.48337337e-02, 5.31865537e-01, 1.56093568e-01],
       [5.86298764e-01, 9.97262597e-01, 6.34290516e-01, 1.00000000e+00],
       [5.97444713e-01, 9.81289029e-01, 6.42550528e-01, 9.91424084e-01],
       [6.00944221e-01, 0.00000000e+00, 6.96744621e-01, 1.08848168e-02],
       [5.74251950e-01, 7.97534823e-01, 6.52808249e-01, 9.11253214e-01],
       [5.76594234e-01, 9.88356769e-01, 6.14586353e-01, 9.95811999e-01],
       [6.49482548e-01, 1.17947564e-01, 7.69276202e-01, 2.12465331e-01],
       [4.43520725e-01, 0.00000000e+00, 4.88523185e-01, 3.06037255e-03],
       [5.73850274e-01, 9.98099804e-01, 6.19951129e-01, 1.00000000e+00],
       [5.88080227e-01, 9.84225333e-01, 6.29365742e-01, 9.92947876e-01],
       [4.63795245e-01, 0.00000000e+00, 5.01449883e-01, 6.69268705e-03],
       [5.98340154e-01, 8.42971087e-01, 6.55794621e-01, 9.12072539e-01],
       [6.37270927e-01, 9.93961275e-01, 6.85116649e-01, 9.98596966e-01],
       [4.52485174e-01, 0.00000000e+00, 4.90930170e-01, 6.75926497e-03],
       [4.75573689e-01, 2.19370006e-04, 5.12709975e-01, 7.29098916e-03],
       [6.35851383e-01, 9.84483540e-01, 6.74637556e-01, 9.93774951e-01],
       [5.68791032e-01, 8.28377008e-01, 6.33071899e-01, 9.21479702e-01],
       [6.47346854e-01, 9.93806422e-01, 6.99080467e-01, 9.99322712e-01],
       [5.27590513e-01, 5.16463578e-01, 5.83534241e-01, 5.73334515e-01],
       [5.64501703e-01, 9.90154684e-01, 6.00881636e-01, 9.97316182e-01],
       [5.77020407e-01, 0.00000000e+00, 6.73190713e-01, 8.89170542e-03],
       [5.32372057e-01, 2.13325815e-03, 5.79382718e-01, 1.05855763e-02],
       [8.98179829e-01, 9.49538112e-01, 9.95757401e-01, 1.00000000e+00],
       [4.99201924e-01, 5.06181300e-01, 5.89679837e-01, 6.16471350e-01],
       [5.21599293e-01, 4.78651732e-01, 5.77003956e-01, 5.33329070e-01],
       [4.50019956e-01, 1.22330472e-01, 5.41050851e-01, 2.47679010e-01],
       [4.29230541e-01, 0.00000000e+00, 4.76692528e-01, 2.87851854e-03],
       [5.62652290e-01, 9.98400152e-01, 6.07492149e-01, 1.00000000e+00],
       [4.87109214e-01, 0.00000000e+00, 5.24568141e-01, 5.97356074e-03],
       [5.90865076e-01, 9.54585433e-01, 6.50085270e-01, 9.82792616e-01],
       [5.74019790e-01, 8.37128580e-01, 6.29044652e-01, 8.99678290e-01],
       [5.53819358e-01, 8.57016563e-01, 6.38536036e-01, 9.92708564e-01],
       [4.83464658e-01, 1.37476027e-01, 5.26389778e-01, 2.12601632e-01],
       [5.96642673e-01, 0.00000000e+00, 6.87337220e-01, 1.86070986e-02],
       [4.97669607e-01, 9.93196428e-01, 5.45862556e-01, 9.98551309e-01],
       [4.99121875e-01, 0.00000000e+00, 5.39442122e-01, 3.23236943e-03],
       [4.84660000e-01, 9.94518518e-01, 5.32520056e-01, 9.99546885e-01],
       [4.40976650e-01, 0.00000000e+00, 4.80491728e-01, 6.86422409e-03],
       [5.49527287e-01, 9.97768939e-01, 5.95556974e-01, 1.00000000e+00],
       [5.15272915e-01, 0.00000000e+00, 5.56237638e-01, 5.66899357e-03],
       [4.92071599e-01, 4.88374949e-01, 5.88230669e-01, 5.52991986e-01],
       [5.38274407e-01, 5.20660639e-01, 5.77628613e-01, 5.94384313e-01],
       [5.63051403e-01, 8.20557296e-01, 6.14975750e-01, 8.86713326e-01],
       [5.54642916e-01, 0.00000000e+00, 6.46643758e-01, 9.22345091e-03],
       [2.36634426e-02, 4.01944248e-03, 9.46529508e-02, 1.34058632e-02],
       [5.73593915e-01, 0.00000000e+00, 6.63180649e-01, 1.62993632e-02],
       [6.20564580e-01, 0.00000000e+00, 7.05988526e-01, 2.11203881e-02],
       [5.41595221e-01, 8.35655257e-04, 5.84146738e-01, 2.76394002e-02],
       [5.35019100e-01, 9.95864511e-01, 5.82375228e-01, 1.00000000e+00],
       [4.70296830e-01, 5.23132443e-01, 5.61518908e-01, 6.35736704e-01],
       [0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 2.24809378e-01, 4.31476653e-01],
       [4.69021201e-01, 9.71517414e-02, 5.23901165e-01, 1.55832961e-01],
       [4.80020583e-01, 6.51456229e-03, 5.30158699e-01, 3.32816690e-02],
       [4.71901923e-01, 9.95348930e-01, 5.20548344e-01, 1.00000000e+00],
       [6.60102069e-01, 9.90527689e-01, 7.13672221e-01, 9.98146236e-01],
       [4.54827368e-01, 4.24538225e-01, 5.26905894e-01, 4.86199707e-01],
       [4.68487084e-01, 6.32896926e-03, 5.18374741e-01, 3.10271867e-02],
       [6.03597522e-01, 9.62240696e-01, 6.60672426e-01, 9.92416143e-01],
       [5.50437331e-01, 0.00000000e+00, 6.85913920e-01, 3.50675546e-02],
       [5.30428112e-01, 4.69184518e-01, 5.82211554e-01, 5.43515205e-01],
       [8.77255440e-01, 9.52708483e-01, 9.69427347e-01, 1.00000000e+00],
       [5.10310709e-01, 9.92310524e-01, 5.58632672e-01, 9.97960567e-01],
       [3.31037417e-02, 1.61963236e-03, 1.10646553e-01, 1.46547714e-02],
       [0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00]],
      dtype=float32) has invalid type <class 'numpy.ndarray'>, must be a string or Tensor. (Can not convert a ndarray into a Tensor or Operation.)
Uncaught exception. Entering post mortem debugging
Running 'cont' or 'step' will restart the program
> /home/nyan/venvpy3_cpu/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py(304)__init__()
-> (fetch, type(fetch), str(e)))
```

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to feed as follow to display.

```
vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
          image_np,
          np.squeeze(box),
              np.squeeze(clses).astype(np.int32),
              np.squeeze(score),
              category_index,
              use_normalized_coordinates=True,
              line_thickness=8)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you overwrite your tensors references with numpy arrays right below the `sess.run`:

```
boxes = box[0]
scores = score[0]
classes = clses[0]
```

So in the next iteration you try to fetch numpy arrays, which doesn't make sense.